# Opencart quickview close after add cart and redirect to current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, opencart

I am using the opencart and theme i am using have a product quickview feature to open product in a popup

if i click to a popup product is added in cart and not updated in outside page but if i refresh the page the cart is updated i want to redirect to the current url after i click add to cart in popup

jquery code after ajax post data is

```
    success: function(json) {
        $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                    if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                        element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                    } else {
                        element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                    }
                }
            }

            if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
            }

            // Highlight any found errors
            $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
        }

        if (json['success']) {


            $('#notification').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

            $('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

            $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
        }
    }
});
```

if i use the window.location the cart popup is not removed

and if i use the `window.location.reload(true);` the page is refreshed in the popup

my website link is 
http://apnakaryana.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=94

click on the product image or name to show the quick view popup al left side

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution for this i fetch the previous url in text in popup
and get it using jquery and use the `window.location` and also use the `parameter '_top'` which allows to redirect to the same window and close the popup

```
$('#notification').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');         

$('#cart-total').html(json['total']);

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

$('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');

alert('Product is Added to the cart');

window.open($('#request_url').text(),'_top');
```